# How to update PR_DISPLAY_NAME for a meeting?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, mapi

PR_DISPLAY_NAME is updated which gets reflected in the folder structure. But the same doesn't get updated when a new meeting option is chosen. Old display name is displayed for the 'from'. PidLidInternetAccountName returns the old PR_DISPLAY_NAME.

How to update the PR_DISPLAY_NAME when 'new meeting' is chosen?

Comment: PR_DSIAPLY_NAME of an IMessage representing a meeting? That property is not used. What does this have to of with PidLidInternetAccountName? Please be more specific - what are you trying to do and why? What exactly does your code do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!                                                                         What property is used to display 'from' when a new meeting is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

`PR_RCVD_REPRESENTING_NAME_W` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0044001F`).

Comment: It's a new meeting that hasn't been sent to invitees. Say:User1 logs in and schedules a meeting. Before sending the invite, 'from' is shown as user1's email id. Which property is used here?  Is it PR_RCVD_REPRESENTING_NAME_W?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/90yZ1.png

Comment: If the item has just been created, use AppoinmtmentItem.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress. If AppoinmtmentItem.SendUsingAccount is null, use Application.Session.Accounts.Item(1).

Comment: Which MAPI property is used here? We have a MAPI service provider which connects to our own backend servers ( Not exchange server ). A profile is created using this service provider. VB is not used here.

Comment: MAPI property for an account? Take a look at an existing message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).